# Starling game resolution in multiplataform

Tags: actionscript-3, air, starling-framework

We're building a game in starling, and we want it to be multiplataform, but we found some problems with resolutions,

we have designed the game for iPad, and we want it to run in samsung galaxy tab 10.1 and iPhone,
The problem we have in SGT 10.1 is that we want to center the content and add an extra background to fix the black tires in the sides, and in iPhone 4, the content is bigger that the screen...

do you know a way to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: The solution is to write your code to size and position your child elements based on the available screen size.  Did you mean to tag this with Flex?  I removed that tag as there is no Flex content in your question.

Comment: check our starling 1.1 release notes and use screenDPI :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link that explains how to develop for multiple resolutions in starling:
http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/multi-resolution_development

Answer (score 0):

If your assets were created from vector graphics, and don't want to stretch the result bitmap. or you don't want to include several texture atlases.
There's an open source library that should do the trick: https://github.com/XTDStudios/DMT

This library renders the vector assets according to what you give it, and cache it on the device.

online tutorial: http://goo.gl/6NhQk