# How to support multiple screen sizes with my app in both Android and IOS Actionscript 3.0

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I'm working on an game and after alot of progress i tested the game on my phone (Samsung s3 mini). When i tested it i realized the game didnt fit the screen, i used 2048*1536 stage size because i wanted to fit the ipad which has the biggest resolution i think, after seing this happen i have been looking all over the internet for help and i think i found the following links the most useful:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/loading_images_library_as3.html

But i still have many questions but first of all let me clarify, what im making is a game, i just want the game to fit the screen (it will work on landscape by the way) i dont want different UIs for each resolution. So my questions are:

1. If I'm planning to make bitmaps for small, normal, large and xlarge
   wouldnt that make the App unnecessarily heavy?
2. Why cant i simply make bitmaps for xlarge and scale them? and how
   do you scale them.
3. From what i understood from the first link, Android will load the
   best fitting assets automatically but how will i Access those
   assets?

Im not very experienced so make it simple please or teach me what i dont know :P . Also i need an answer quick or else i wont get my drawings done :(.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520622/starling-game-resolution-in-multiplataform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a framework like Starling that will handle this for you. If you don't want to use Starling, maybe you can see how it works there:

```
// create a suitable viewport for the screen size
// 
// we develop the game in a *fixed* coordinate system of 320x480; the game might 
// then run on a device with a different resolution; for that case, we zoom the 
// viewPort to the optimal size for any display and load the optimal textures.

var viewPort:Rectangle = RectangleUtil.fit(
       new Rectangle(0, 0, stageWidth, stageHeight), 
       new Rectangle(0, 0, stage.fullScreenWidth, stage.fullScreenHeight), 
       ScaleMode.SHOW_ALL);
var scaleFactor:int = viewPort.width < 480 ? 1 : 2; // midway between 320 and 640
var appDir:File = File.applicationDirectory;
var assets:AssetManager = new AssetManager(scaleFactor);
assets.verbose = Capabilities.isDebugger;
assets.enqueue(
            appDir.resolvePath("audio"),
            appDir.resolvePath(formatString("fonts/{0}x", scaleFactor)),
            appDir.resolvePath(formatString("textures/{0}x", scaleFactor))
);
```

https://github.com/PrimaryFeather/Starling-Framework/blob/master/samples/scaffold_mobile/src/Scaffold_Mobile.as

Comment: But why not use the highest resolution and the best quality textures so instead of zooming in you just zoom out and you dont need to load other textures and it wont look blurry? Thanks by the way

Comment: Uhh when should i use the Scaffold_Mobile function? How does it work?

Comment: it's not a function but a complete project to get started, Try reading that free book from Thibault Imbert http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024217.do

Comment: I need something i can learn about faster, i need to know what asset sizes will i need before february so please help!

Comment: If you're familiar with AS3, you should have plenty of time to get started with starling by february... just try running their example source code.

Comment: Im not familiar i am new to it

Comment: But i cant! i have only 2 days left!

Comment: stackoverflow won't get job done for you :) Good luck!

Comment: Ok one last question and ill mark your answer as useful, would it look fine if i make bitmaps for the 4 general DPIs and scale them up or down depending on the device?

Comment: if you target 1024x768 pixels, you should be fine on large devices. But it takes a lot of memory to load large images so you will certainly need to have a duplicate copy of your assets to half the scale, so that your app doesn t crash on ipad 1 and older devices.